# Horizontal scroll bar of a ScrolledComposite not visible

Tags: java, user-interface, scroll, swt, eclipse-rap

I read all old questions related to this issue but I didn't solve it.
Could someone helps me with this because I'm already run out of ideas.
Here is my code:

```
    ScrolledComposite panelHolder = new ScrolledComposite(composite, SWT.H_SCROLL | SWT.V_SCROLL);
    panelHolder.setLayout(new FillLayout());
    panelHolder.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    FormToolkit toolkit = UIConstants.getToolkit();
    toolkit.setBorderStyle(SWT.NONE);
    tableViewer = new TableViewer(toolkit.createTable(panelHolder, border ? SWT.BORDER : SWT.NONE));
    tableViewer.setContentProvider(new TableContentProvider());
    ColumnViewerToolTipSupport.enableFor(tableViewer);
    TableViewerColumn viewerColumn = new TableViewerColumn(tableViewer, SWT.NONE);
    viewerColumn.setLabelProvider(labelProvider);
    Table table = tableViewer.getTable();
    table.setLinesVisible(false);
    addControlListener(viewerColumn);

    panelHolder.setContent(table);
    panelHolder.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    panelHolder.setExpandVertical(true);
    panelHolder.setMinSize(table.computeSize(SWT.DEFAULT, SWT.DEFAULT));
    panelHolder.layout();
```

Comment: Why put a table in a scrolled composite? The table can do scroll bars on its own and putting it in a scrolled composite often causes issues.

Comment: Because without a scrolled composite even the vertical scroll does not appear. The table style was SWT.V-SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL. The view contains pages of elements and 'show more...' functionality which adds new elements to the already added ones. When you set the page size to 5 for example, when you reach the bottom of the view, the vertical scroll does not appear. That's why I tried another approach with a ScrolledComposite.